# postgrest post request -Getting Error for string passing in raw sql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3, postgrest

I am getting error for raw sql if i am using any string literals inside the sql query.

```
http://localhost:3000/db/test
{
"sql": "select * from party where party_name='xxx' "
}

error:

{"length":92,"name":"error","severity":"ERROR","code":"42703","position":"40","file":"parse_expr.c","line":"768","routine":"transformColumnRef"}

but the request with integer working fine..ex:
http://localhost:3000/db/test
{
"sql": "select * from party where id=1"
}
```

Comment: i think u did mistake your query.please check your query again

Comment: Check out: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/errcodes-appendix.html. Error code 42703 means "undefined_column", so probably the column party_name does not exist

Comment: @Tommaso : The same query returns result when executing in psql console. Here problem rise when using rest api (postgresql-http-server is using now)